# Jeet Gird - Can I use Fixed gutters?

Tags: jeet-grid

Is there any way I can use fixed gutters with Jeet.gs?
I am using the SASS version of the grid.

http://jeet.gs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Jeet does not allow fixed gutters.

If you need to use fixed gutters you can check the new [LostGrid](https://github.com/corysimmons/lost) project created by Cory Simmons (the author of Jeet).

Comment: Nice one. LostGrid with calc() looks like the solution. Thank you!